# How to centre the content block within the footer

Tags: html, css

Apologies for pasting a big html but I have been struggling to fix the css and it will take too much work to try and shorten the code, so instead I want to show the full screenshot and the code behind it.

If you look at the screenshot, the whole content block within the footer is closer to the left edge. I want the whole content block to be in the centre but don't know how to do it.

[image]

Basic CSS:

```
.footer_wrap .columns_wrap {
margin-left: 30px; // this actually does shift the content more to the right but don't think this is idea in terms definite have it smack bang in the centre
 margin-right: 0px;
}

.footer_wrap {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<footer class="footer_wrap widget_area scheme_original">
   <div class="footer_wrap_inner widget_area_inner">
      <div class="content_wrap">
         <div class="columns_wrap">
            <aside id="text-4" class="widget_number_6 column-1_5 widget widget_text">
               <div class="textwidget">
                  <div class="logofooteri"><img src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/123d.png"></div>
                  <div class="socialfooter" style="padding-bottom: 15px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                     <p><a style="float: left; margin-right: 12px;" href="https://www.instagram.com/balancecoffee" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow"><img loading="lazy" src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Instagramwhite.svg" width="30px" height="30px"></a><a style="float: left; margin-right: 12px;" href="https://www.facebook.com/balancecoffee20" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow"><img loading="lazy" src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Facebookwhite.svg" width="29px" height="29px"></a></p>
                     <p><a style="float: left; margin-right: 12px;" href="https://twitter.com/BalanceCoffeeUK" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow"><img loading="lazy" src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Twitterwhite.svg" width="30px" height="30px"></a></p>
                     <p><a style="float: left; margin-right: 12px;" href="https://www.pinterest.com/balancecoffee" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow"><img loading="lazy" src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Pinterestwhite.svg" width="30px" height="30px"></a></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="footer-address">Kemp House, 152-160 City Road,<br>
                     London, EC1V 2NX
                  </div>
                  <div class="footer-address">info@balancecoffee.co.uk</div>
               </div>
            </aside>
            <aside id="nav_menu-6" class="widget_number_7 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu">
               <h5 class="widget_title">ACCOUNT</h5>
               <div class="menu-account-footer-container">
                  <ul id="menu-account-footer-1" class="menu">
                     <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7970"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=285">Sign In</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7971"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=6089">Earn Rewards</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7968"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=4561">Manage Subscription</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7969"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=1109">FAQs</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7967"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=1032">Contact</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </aside>
            <aside id="nav_menu-7" class="widget_number_8 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu">
               <h5 class="widget_title">SHOP</h5>
               <div class="menu-shop-footer-container">
                  <ul id="menu-shop-footer-1" class="menu">
                     <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-7995"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?cat=69">Coffee</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-7978"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?product_cat=subscription-coffee">Subscription Coffee</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-7980"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?product_cat=coffee-equipment">Coffee Equipment</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-4757 current_page_item menu-item-7989"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=4757" aria-current="page">Sage Coffee Machines</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-7979"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?product_cat=oat-milk-coffee-bundles">Oat Milk</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-7985"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?product_cat=coffee-gifts">Coffee Gifts</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </aside>
            <aside id="nav_menu-8" class="widget_number_9 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu">
               <h5 class="widget_title">ABOUT</h5>
               <div class="menu-about-footer-menu-container">
                  <ul id="menu-about-footer-menu-1" class="menu">
                     <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8015"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=1012">Our Story</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8038"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=1054">Sustainability</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-8039"><a href="/">Affiliates</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8040"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=1109">FAQs</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-8041"><a href="/">Press</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-8042"><a href="/">Become an Affiliate</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8043"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=2410">Become a Stocklist</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </aside>
            <aside id="nav_menu-9" class="widget_number_10 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu">
               <h5 class="widget_title">BARISTA SCHOOL</h5>
               <div class="menu-barista-school-footer-menu-container">
                  <ul id="menu-barista-school-footer-menu-1" class="menu">
                     <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8035"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=3249">Coffee Blog</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-4757 current_page_item menu-item-8032"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=4757" aria-current="page">Sage Coffee Machines</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8031"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=3238">Coffee Videos</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8033"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=3241">Coffee Recipes</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8034"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=3252">Tips &amp; Hacks</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </aside>
            <div class="abovecontentright">
               <img src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/23ewd.jpg">
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- /.columns_wrap -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.content_wrap -->
   </div>
   <!-- /.footer_wrap_inner -->
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are not posting working examples and not even posting full styles to reproduce your code I can just guess for the next solutions.

Start with applying `width:100%;` to wrappers and `margin-right: auto, margin-left: auto;` to block that should be centered. It's an old-style way to center the block but should work fine.

```
   <div class="footer_wrap_inner widget_area_inner">
      <div class="content_wrap">
         <div class="columns_wrap">
```

Looks like it will be `width: 100%` for `footer_wrap_inner` and `content_wrap`, and `margin-right: auto, margin-left: auto;` for `columns_wrap`. But you need to check it.

Also, I see that you are using floats in your code, it will be better to rewrite code with flex and use its built-in centering features (or even align content to both sides with the help of `justify-content: space-between`)